# Talend: How to return values from tRunJob in tESBProviderResponse?

Tags: talend

Is there something special needed when running a subjob within a web service?

I know I can pass in values via the context of the tRunJob and retrieve values via the tRunJob schema (presented via a tBufferOutput component). 
 However, this doesn't seem to work when being run from a web service; i.e., a tESBConsumer invoking a service containing a tESBProviderRequest and a tESBProviderResponse.  Passing values via tRunJob context works but retrieving values via tRunJob schema does not work.  In the below output, the "service_received_from_child" output shows null values from the tRunJob.

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3744
[statistics] connected
.------------------.
|  client_passed_to_service |
|=----------------=|
|Id                |
|=----------------=|
|a7d0b000000XamBAAS|
'------------------'

.------+------.
|client_received_from_service |
|=-----+-----=|
|Status|CaseId|
|=-----+-----=|
'------+------'

[statistics] disconnected

.------------------.
|  child_received_from_service |
|=----------------=|
|Id                |
|=----------------=|
|a7d0b000000XamBAAS|
'------------------'

.------------------------------------+----------.
|                child_returned_to_service      |
|=-----------------------------------+---------=|
|result                              |case_id   |
|=-----------------------------------+---------=|
|Test: Received Id a7d0b000000XamBAAS|0987654321|
'------------------------------------+----------'

.------------------.
|  service_passed_to_child |
|=----------------=|
|Id                |
|=----------------=|
|a7d0b000000XamBAAS|
'------------------'

.------+-------.
|service_received_from_child |
|=-----+------=|
|result|case_id|
|=-----+------=|
|null  |null   |
'------+-------'
```

I built a test parent job to execute the same child job and it is working correctly, passing in values via tRunJob context and retrieving values from tRunJob schema.  In the below output, the "parent_received_from_child" output shows the correct results from the tRunJob.

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 4045
[statistics] connected
.------------------.
|  child_received_from_parent |
|=----------------=|
|Id                |
|=----------------=|
|a7d0b000000XamBAAS|
'------------------'

.------------------------------------+----------.
|                child_returned_to_parent       |
|=-----------------------------------+---------=|
|result                              |case_id   |
|=-----------------------------------+---------=|
|Test: Received Id a7d0b000000XamBAAS|0987654321|
'------------------------------------+----------'

.------------------------------------+----------.
|                parent_received_from_child     |
|=-----------------------------------+---------=|
|result                              |case_id   |
|=-----------------------------------+---------=|
|Test: Received Id a7d0b000000XamBAAS|0987654321|
'------------------------------------+----------'

[statistics] disconnected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:  It seems that the input flow cannot be connected directly to the tRunJob but must first pass through a tFlowToIterate and then to the tRunJob.  Making this change, the client is receiving the correct values.

I'm guessing because the web service runs continuously and each request is a new "row" through the flow so the iterate is needed in order to process each request separately(?)